# Validate URL paths with a specified amount of parts only

Tags: python, regex

just trying to work out the regex for this. Say I have to following list of URL paths

```
/v1/users/
/v1/users/123abc/
/v1/users/123abc/456def/
/v1/users/123abc/456def/789ghi/
/v1/users/123abc/me/
/v1/users/123abc/me/456def/
```

where some parts are set, like `v1` and `users`, and some parts are path parameters so they can be any values/characters, like `123abc` and `456def`.

What regex pattern can I put in place for the path parameters so it matches against the right ones.

For example, I tried to get `/v1/users/123abc/456def/` using `^/v1/users/.*?/.*?/$`. However, this regex matched with the following:

```
/v1/users/123abc/456def/
/v1/users/123abc/456def/789ghi/
/v1/users/123abc/me/
/v1/users/123abc/me/456def/
```

I understand it may be impossible to not match with `/v1/users/123abc/me/` however I have a way around this if someone can find a solution which can get both `/v1/users/123abc/456def/` and `/v1/users/123abc/me/`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace both `.*?` with  `[^/]*` or even `[^/]+`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks a lot, knew I was close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace both `.*?` with `[^/]*` or even `[^/]+` (as subparts must contain at least one char) and use

```
^/v1/users/[^/]+/[^/]+/$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X6bmLQ/1%60).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `/v1/users/` - a literal string
- `[^/]+` - one or more chars other than `/`
- `/` - a `/` char
- `[^/]+` - one or more chars other than `/`
- `/` - a `/` char
- `$` - end of string.